# Listening to documents in a timed Firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've created a node.js function that finds documents in my firestore database, and it works successfully, but I'm querying it with .get()

Is there any way I can trigger a function that will await to complete until a document is found (as the documents are uploaded by a different app) and set on a timer, so that if the timer runs out and no documents are found (say 5 minutes) it will return a null document value?

My current function looks like this right now:

```
export const createFinder = async (latitude, longitude, orderUid) => {

    // Find cities within 5km of location
    
    const radiusInM = 50 * 100;

    const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds([latitude, longitude], radiusInM);
    const promises = [];
    
    for (const b of bounds) {
    const q = db.collection('availableDocuments')
        .orderBy('geohash')
        .startAt(b[0])
        .endAt(b[1]);

        const snapshot = await q.get();
        promises.push(snapshot);
    }

    return promises;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your are looking for [Firestore triggered Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). You can use `onCreate()` that'll trigger a function every time a document is added.

```
exports.fnName = functions.firestore
  .document('col/{docId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log(snap.data())
  });
```

I don't see a Cloud Function in your question. Are you running this logic somewhere else? You can use a [Firestore listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) then as shown below:

```
const q = "..." // your query

q.onSnapshot((qSnap) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === "added") {
      console.log("New Doc: ", change.doc.data());
      // Run function 
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: So it's a function in itself. It is a function that gets triggered when a user clicks 
an 'accept order' button. So when the user accepts the order, the function gets triggered and scans to see who is available (represented as a document upload) in 'availableDocuments'. I want the scanning process to last on a set timer for 5 mins, and if a document is uploaded, it will end the function. Or, if 5 mins are up, the function returns null. Is this possible with onCreate()?

Comment: @James666 so you trigger a "Cloud Function" when user clicks the accept button and you want to wait for a document to be added in that CF? I mean it is possible to keep a function alive for 5 min for sure.  Just to confirm again, you want to listen for the update in function right and not client side? Also what are you trying to do and is it necessary to return a response to client with something or null?

Comment: That's exactly correct, yes. I want to listen for the update in the function and not on the client side. I'm trying to scan for new documents to come about - it's scanning for nearby users within a range based off a geohash. When users click an 'online' button, it creates a document with their uid as the document name, and has data of their geohash and their latitude/longitude. It's not necessary to return something to the client as a response, but it would be good to listen to any updates for 5 mins, and if those 5 mins end we can return a null value

Comment: @James666 assuming `createFinder` is your Cloud Function (triggered by user), it won't be nice to keep it running for 5 minutes at least from billing perspective as you don't have to return any thing to the client. Instead you can use the Firestore triggers as in my answer that'll trigger a new function every time a new doc is added to provided collection (and not just for 5 minutes). If you want to process something only for the entries within 5 minutes, then you can compare the doc added time with your start time, if it's less than 5 min then proceed else no.

Comment: Please add the complete existing cloud function & screenshots of Firestore if I have not understood the dataflow correctly.

Comment: I did it, it worked well. But what I did was, I triggered the function, and then if no documents were found from the trigger, I listened for new documents to arise into the collection from the onSnapshot() function and then trigger the function again. I think it's a good work around, and it is based on the onCreate() method you mentioned